# bash choosing latest version of a file from a list

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have the following 'structure' of file names in a directory:

```
ABC_abcabc_ver01.txt
ABC_abcabc_ver02.txt
ABC_abcabc_ver04.txt
DEF_defdef_ver01.txt
GHI_ghighi_ver01.txt
GHI_ghighi_ver08.txt
```

What I would like to get is the list of the latest versions only (max last digit in a file's name), i.e.,

```
ABC_abcabc_ver04.txt
DEF_defdef_ver01.txt
GHI_ghighi_ver08.txt
```

Note that the digits are not necessarily consecutive, and not all the files have multiple versions. For simplicity, one can assume that the maximum possible version is '09', but would be cool to have a more generic solution. I know about `awk` (no `sed`), so there are chances I'd understand a `awk`-based idea. Would welcome any help.

Comment: Switch to proper version control.  Once your sanity begins to recover, you will not regret it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can `ls -1 or find...` and pipe to:

```
awk -F '_ver' '{a[$1]=$2>a[$1]?$2:a[$1]}END{for(x in a)print x FS a[x]}'
```

test with your data as standard input:

```
kent$  awk -F '_ver' '{a[$1]=$2>a[$1]?$2:a[$1]}END{for(x in a)print x FS a[x]}' <<<"ABC_abcabc_ver01.txt
ABC_abcabc_ver02.txt
ABC_abcabc_ver04.txt
DEF_defdef_ver01.txt
GHI_ghighi_ver01.txt
GHI_ghighi_ver08.txt"
```

output:

```
GHI_ghighi_ver08.txt
ABC_abcabc_ver04.txt
DEF_defdef_ver01.txt
```

**EDIT**

add "comments", as OP asked:

```
awk -F '_ver'                   #use "_ver" as field separator
'{a[$1]=$2>a[$1]?$2:a[$1]}      #build an arry(hashtable),key:1st field, value:2nd filed (I guess you understood a=b>a?b:a)
END{for(x in a)print x FS a[x]}'#at the end, print all elements from the array
```

Comment: Cheers @Kent, seems to do the job! But could you please comment a bit on the awk code? Especially on the part in the first curly braces? I'd like to understand what's happening. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to do it with pure bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s extglob
declare -A filesDict
export LC_COLLATE=C # so that * expansion order is always the same

for curFile in *; do
    extension=${curFile#*.}
    filename=${curFile%%+([[:digit:]]).*} # get rid of the version number and extension
    if [[ $curFile == "$filename"+([[:digit:]])".$extension" ]]; then # if doing it backwards results in the same filename. We do that to ignore other random files that might appear in a directory
        filesDict["$filename.$extension"]=$curFile # add or overwrite value in the dictionary. Overwriting is always safe because files with the biggest version number will always come last (assuming that they're zero-padded)
    fi
done

for curKey in "${!filesDict[@]}"
do
    echo "File: $curKey    Last version: ${filesDict[$curKey]}"
done
```

This script relies on the bash behavior that expands `*` using alphabetical order. I'm not sure whether all locales do it right for numbers, so I force `LC_COLLATE=C` just to be sure.

Now, if you ignore the fact that this script is too tricky, you will realize that it is actually a very good solution, because it can handle any filenames you can have (even those that have newlines in the name).

It will also handle the case when you have same filenames but with different extensions (like `test01.txt` and `test01.tar.gz`, these are going to be treated as different files)

It will ignore files that have no extension or no version number. If you want to include files without version number then just change `+([[:digit:]])` to `*([[:digit:]])` (note that there are two occurrences of it in the script). You can also remove the dot to include filenames without an extension, but that's a whole different story.

Answer (score 1):

```
sort -t _ -k1,1 -k2,2 -k 3.4nr file|awk -F _ '!a[$1 FS $2]++'

ABC_abcabc_ver04.txt
DEF_defdef_ver01.txt
GHI_ghighi_ver08.txt
```

**explain:**

The sort command will sort the file as expect:

```
ABC_abcabc_ver04.txt
ABC_abcabc_ver02.txt
ABC_abcabc_ver01.txt
DEF_defdef_ver01.txt
GHI_ghighi_ver08.txt
GHI_ghighi_ver01.txt
```

awk command take the latest one always (the first one).

Comment: What a genius solution! I wrote an analysis of how this works [here](https://gist.github.com/caruccio/804d53d19c7c993aba31dbd3da4c9d68).